# bf4 how to get the 3X scope m1911

Tags: battlefield-4

How do I unlock the 3 times scope for the M1911?

What I saw on Google is that you had to be online on 5 December?

That day I wasn't online and didn't receive the scope.

I have got premium.

Comment: It's worth noting that you must have the M1911 pistol unlocked in order to use the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of problems on the 5th and with the 1911 scope not unlocking properly, [they later unlocked the scope for all in a later patch.](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/news/view/m1911-scope-available/)

If you didn't get yours, and you have the 1911 unlocked, contact customer support.

Comment: I'll try contacting them

Comment: It has magically appeared in battlelog(without contacting the support)